# Wordpress : $authors_posts no me devuelve el autor

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

Intento hacer un `var_dump` para verificar si me trae el nombre el autor, pero me sale `null` o.o

Este es el código:

```
<?php
$authors_posts = get_posts( array(
'author' => 19,
'numberposts' => 1,
'orderby' => 'date'
)
);

var_dump($authors_posts->post_author);
?>
```

Comment: ¿ Cuál es su función `get_posts`? ¿Qué retorna si hace `var_dump($authors_posts)`

Comment: En WordPress puedes obtener el nombre del autor del post mediante [`get_the_author();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author/). Por ejemplo: `$author = get_the_author();`, tendrás en la variable el nombre del autor.